Why some of compiler errors don't have error codes?
Here is an example of an error with a code:
fn main() {
    let hi = foo;
}

error[E0425]: cannot find value `foo` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:2:14
  |
2 |     let hi = foo;
  |              ^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `hei` (bin "hei") due to 1 previous error

However, this program will give an error with no code:
fn main() {
    let 1_i32 << 32;
}

error: expected a pattern, found an expression
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 | let 1_i32 << 32;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ arbitrary expressions are not allowed in patterns

error: could not compile `hei` (bin "hei") due to 1 previous error

If we remove let keyword like this, it will return a different error from a lint:
fn main() {
    1_i32 << 32;
}

error: this arithmetic operation will overflow
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     1_i32 << 32;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to shift left by `32_i32`, which would overflow
  |
  = note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default

These are from Rust 1.79.0.
Why some errors have a code (and a explanation through rustc --explain), some are lints and some are... just errors?
I read the rustc book's chapters on Errors and lints. I was expecting to find the answer, but I didn't find anything helpful.

This is a question about the design of the compiler, so I consulted the Rust Compiler Development Guide and found this statement about “Error codes and explanations”:

Most errors have an associated error code. Error codes are linked to long-form explanations which contains an example of how to trigger the error and in-depth details about the error. They may be viewed with the --explain flag, or via the error index.
As a general rule, give an error a code (with an associated explanation) if the explanation would give more information than the error itself.

So, errors have error codes when there’s something worth saying about the error that can’t reasonably be put directly into the error message.
You can browse the error index to see what kind of explanations there are. Often, they contain simple example code and discussion of how that code is erroneous. You can imagine that it would be confusing and verbose if the compiler printed this example code alongside the error in your code!
There isn’t any documentation of why not to use an error code, but I can imagine that it would be extra work to add a code for every individual case where the compiler produces an error, or decide whether an error is really the same kind as an existing error. And it would mean the error index would get very large, particularly since it covers not only all errors in the current version of the compiler but all previous versions. (Error codes stop being produced when errors are re-classified into different categories, or become allowed instead of rejected due to new language features.)

To expand on @KevinReid's answer, the cases I know that errors don't have error code are two: syntax errors and lints.
Syntax errors don't have an error code because it's not useful: it cannot tell more than "your file has an invalid Rust syntax" (unless we give a specific code to each error, which is unworkable). This is your first snippet (error: expected a pattern, found an expression).
Lints, like your second snippet (error: this arithmetic operation will overflow), can have more information, but it's in another place: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rustc/lints/listing/index.html, grouped by their severity (deny, warn or allow). They are recognizable via the last line in the error, note: `#[deny/warn(lint_name)]` on by default.
